# Usage of past perfect tense

Tags: tense

People say "I've never thought about it" when they don't have experience of thinking about something.

Then, few hours later, How can I say to describe at that moment?

For example, 
1 PM : I said, **I've never thought about it.**

10 PM : **I already thought about it** 9 hours ago but I want to describe at that moment. I suppose it should be "**I had never thought about it**". Is it correct? I've never heard about this sentence, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct to use the pluperfect tense for this situation

```
Until that time I had never thought about it.
```

This is correct when you are referring to a state of affairs -having never thought about it -which was valid in the past but which is no longer valid because now you have thought about it.